# Copy Worksheet from one workbook to another. Type Mismatch 13

Tags: vba, excel

I'm looking to copy just one worksheet from a workbook to another and then change the name. Nothing hugely fancy.

I keep getting a type-mismatch error and I don't know why. I've used code from others which they say works but just doesn't for me.

Any ideas.

```
Private Sub cmdStockLog_Click()

week = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Stock Sheet").Range("F1")

Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Data\FOH Stock.xlsx")

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Stock Sheet").Copy After:=Workbooks(wb).Sheets(Worksheets.Count)
ActiveSheet.Name = "WK" & week

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Private Sub cmdStockLog_Click()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim week

    week = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Stock Sheet").Range("F1")

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Data\FOH Stock.xlsx")

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Stock Sheet").Copy After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)
    Set ws = wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count) ' new sheet
    ws.Name = "WK" & week
End Sub
```